# Raspberry Pi to AB controllogix: how to trigger output in GPIO based on continuosly reading plc tag value

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, plc

I've discovered pylogix on GitHub and have been playing around with reading/writing tags on an AB L71 CPU. I am successful at the read/write part, but what I want to do is trigger a GPIO pin output based on plc value being larger than 0.

I can't seem to figure out what I need to do to get the constantly updated value into the output function.

```
import threading
from pylogix.eip import PLC
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep

comm = PLC()
comm.IPAddress = '10.201.191.177'

def readdata():
    threading.Timer(1.0, readdata).start()
    x = comm.Read('parts')
    print (x)
readdata()

if x > 0:
relay = LED(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nice to see I'm not the only one interested in PLCs on this forum.  I might recommend this for you:

Edit:
 I read the docs for your module.  try this new code below
docs can be found https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

```
import threading # I don't think this is necessity for your application
import time
from pylogix.eip import PLC
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep

with PLC() as comm #small edit here to control the closing of sockets upon exit
    comm.IPAddress = '10.201.191.177'
    running=True
    relay = LED(2) #I believe the previous version of your code was constantly overwriting your 'relay' variable with a new instance of class LED
    while running==True:
        x=comm.read('parts')
        if x > 0:
            relay.on()
        else: relay.off()
    time.sleep(.5)
#this will run forever updating your LED every 500ms, I would recommend writing code to exit this loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm trying to use the RPI as an ethernet/ip alarm/lightstack and avoid running a lot of conduit for a hardwired option (alarm is for non-safety related machine faults.) Your solution leads me back to the original problem I was having: the relay output wants to continuously cycle on/off everytime the PLC tag is read. I think I need a way to isolate the output to the relay from the continuously reading tag.

Comment: Works great, thank you for your help. I should have read more about gpiozero first...